# Get Data from Database using VBA Excel

Tags: sql, vba, database

I'm trying to collect some data from a database using VBA code

I have the following

[image]

I have 2 variables (`VIN_T` & `PN5D_T`) and I want to return he `RO_Num`, for that, I have to use as a filter the 2 variables on my database. I have declared:

```
strQuery = "SELECT [RONum] FROM [dbo].[Warranty] WHERE RIGHT([VIN],6)=VIN_T AND LEFT([PN],5)=PN5D_T"
```

However, I get an error: `Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14) Invalid column name 'VIN_T'`, I have tested the same query code with the direct value and the code works

```
strQuery = "SELECT [RONum] FROM [dbo].[Warranty] WHERE RIGHT([VIN],6)='470765' AND LEFT([PN],5)='27301'"
```

I have declared both variables as:

```
Dim VIN_T As String
Dim PN5D_T As String
```

So i don´t understand why I'm getting this error, therefore, I would like to know, how can I pass the 2 variables on my `strQuery`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Set a break point and inspect the value of `strQuery`.  That should give you some insight.

Comment: Advise not to use variable names same as field names. Must concatenate variables or use parameters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access

Comment: In the first query, the value of VIN_T is not be inserted into the string but rather the string VIN_T which is then evaluated as a column name.  You must concatenate as @June7 mentioned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [concatenate in VBA ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276656/concatenate-in-vba-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```vb
strQuery = "SELECT [RONum] FROM [dbo].[Warranty] WHERE " & _
           " RIGHT([VIN],6)='" & VIN_T & "' AND " & _
           " LEFT([PN],5)='" & PN5D_T &"'"
```